# Будильники на Spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, email

У меня есть объекты рассылки, в которых есть параметр времени. В это время они должны быть отправлены на e-mail пользователям.

В данный момент реализовано так: есть Scheduler, который просыпается каждые 15 минут, смотрит, есть ли неотправленные письма, которые он проспал и отправляет. т.е. допустим есть рассылка со временем отправки в 8:00. Также допустим, что Scheduler просыпается в 8:07, смотрит в базу. В базе лежит неотправленное письмо. Он берёт это письмо и отправляет.

Я так понимаю, нужно создать какой-то "будильник", который будет срабатывать в определенное время и отправлять письма. И ставить Scheduler на проверку раз в секунду довольно дорого.

**Как мне средствами Spring создать отправку письма в какое-то *конкретное* время?**

За примеры кода или ссылки на туториалы буду особо благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть в spring аннотация @Scheduled, ее можно использовать с параметрами, как у планировщика cron:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    System.out.println(
      "schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
}
```

Т.е. запускать этот метод в 10:15 AM 15th числа каждый месяц.

Comment: Как его настроить на то, чтобы не каждое 15е число каждого месяца и не в то время, которое я кодом задам, а, чтобы в какое-то динамическое время выполнялся метод? Чтобы каждое письмо уходило в своё время, которое задано как свойство этого письма

Comment: Добавь поле в таблицу с датой и временем отправки. Напиши сервис, который будет по этому полю отправлять сообщение. А по шедулеру этот метод будет запускаться, например каждые 15 минут ежедневно.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь моментальную отправку сообщений, то в простейшем случае тебе стоит посмотреть в сторону объекта [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), который можно шарить между компонентом, который генерирует сообщения и которых их отправляет. Псевдокод будет примерно таким:

```java
class MyMessage{
//.... поля и т.д.
}

class MessageGenerator{
  private final BlockingQueue<MyMessage> queue; 

  //.... поля и т.д.

  public void send(MyMessage message) {
      queue.put(message);
  }

}

class MessageSender implements Runnable{

  private final BlockingQueue<MyMessage> queue; 

 //.... поля и т.д.

  public void run(){
      while(true) {
         MyMessage message = queue.take(); //это ожидание в реальном времени
         //дальше собственно отправка
      }
  }
}
```

Однако, раз у тебя присутствует БД, то скорее всего тебе нужна какая-то отказоустойчивость, чтобы ещё не отправленные письма не пропали при аварии/перезапуске сервера. В таком случае стоит посмотреть в сторону очередей типа ActiveMq/RabbitMq/Kafka и т.д. Но даже твоё решение с БД является вполне рабочим. Просто сократи поллинг с 15 минут до 1 минуты, или даже до 30 секунд. Такая погрешность в отправке писем считается вполне нормальной и практикуется почти везде.